# How to get Image Height and Width from Image which Location is stored in the database?

Tags: php, html, css

I need to get the height and width of an image in order to set stretch it according to the size of the div. I could have used max-width:100% and max-height:100% but there are some images that are smaller than the div so I decided I would just manually assign the width and height.

I prefer to get these dimensions in php imagesy() and imagesx().

```
   <?php $h=imagesy($list['Image1']); 
    $ w = imagesy($list['Image1'])?>

   <img src="<?php echo $list['Image1']; ?>"
    <?php if($h>$w) echo"style='height:100%;'";
    else echo"style='width:100%;'"; ?> />
```

Comment: Btw, the content of $list['Image1']; is the link of the photo:

Comment: Eg. admin/products/Test 1/10384747_680658022002661.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP functions like `getimagesize()` will return the dimensions of an image. But you are first going to have the load the image into the function. In other words you're going to have to fetch the image first.

If you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled then you should be able to invoke it with an absolute URL:

```
$size = getimagesize("http://www.example.com/gifs/logo.gif");
```

Comment: Thanks! I read just now that the width and height are stored in an array. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to read just now that getimagesize returns an array with the width at [0] and height at [1]. So I was still able to compare them directly, hence, dynamically resizing them to fit the div containing the image. ;)

```
    <?php $h=(getimagesize($list['Image1']));?>
    <img src="<?php echo $list['Image1']; ?>" 
    style="<?php 
    if($h[0]>$h[1])
    {
        echo'width:100%;margin:0 auto;';    
    }
    else
    {
        echo'height:100%;vertical-alignment:auto;'; 
    } ?>"
    alt="<?php echo $list['Image1']; ?>" />
```

Comment: what I can't understand is why you didn't use just CSS. Like you mentioned max-width:100% and max-height:100%, just add width:auto; height:auto; and you'd have a lot less coding and the same rendering

Comment: There are images which are smaller than the div containing them.

Comment: yes, and width:auto; height:auto will cover that (then you set max-width and max-height to 100%)